# Extend datagrid in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

Hi does anyone knows what functions do I have to overwrite to make myDataGridEx(that derives from DataGrid) to use instead of:
DataGridRow -> use DataGridRowEx, 
DataGridRowHeader -> use DataGridRowHeaderEx, 
DataGridRowHeader -> use DataGridRowHeaderEx, 
DataGridRowGroupHeader -> use DataGridRowGroupHeaderEx, 
DataGridColumnHeader -> use DataGridColumnHeaderEx, 
DataGridCell -> use DataGridCellEx

I will create and Extend the Ex classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible do that with simple overriding. You can download source code of toolkit, get project with DataGrid and change source code extending functionality.